# Jenkins groovy scripted pipeline variables not substituting correctly

Tags: bash, shell, maven, jenkins, groovy

I'm running a very simple pipeline to create maven projects, the pipeline is to run a single maven install command.

The trouble is substituting variables into the one-liner. I've tried various different things but stuck in a strange place. Take example pipeline below:

```java
node {
    stage('Set Vars') {
        GIT_HASH = sh (script: "git log -n 1 --pretty=format:'%H'" , returnStdout: true)
        echo "git hash is >>>>>>>> $GIT_HASH"
        BUILD_NUM="${env.BUILD_NUMBER}"
        echo "build no is >>>>>>>> ${BUILD_NUM}"
    }
    stage('Build Project') {
        sh "mvn clean install -PrunInstallPackage -Duser=admin -Dpass=guessing -Dip=200.0.0.1 -Dport=4444 -Dhash=${GIT_HASH} -Dbuildnumber=${BUILD_NUM}"
    }
}
```

I would expect to see the variables substitued in the mvn install command, this does not seem to work this way though.

This build results in:

```
sh "mvn clean install -PrunInstallPackage -Duser=admin -Dpass=guessing -Dip=200.0.0.1 -Dport=4444 -Dhash=${GIT_HASH}
```

Both echo commands print out correct output.

Why does the last command get cut off after the first variable substitution?

Also, for some unknown reason, I cannot substitute `-Dbuildnumber=${env.BUILD_NUMBER}"` directly into the maven command. Seems like something that a user should be able to do. What am I missing here?

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am trying to remember how I solved same issues in the past..

**Problem 1**

You are using the `GIT_HASH` variable across two stages, so you have to declare it global to share it across them:

```java
// Global variables declaration

GIT_HASH = null

// Pipeline code

node {
    stage('Set Vars') {
        GIT_HASH = sh (script: "git log -n 1 --pretty=format:'%H'" , returnStdout: true)
        echo "git hash is >>>>>>>> $GIT_HASH"
        BUILD_NUM="${env.BUILD_NUMBER}"
        echo "build no is >>>>>>>> ${BUILD_NUM}"
    }
    stage('Build Project') {
        sh "mvn clean install -PrunInstallPackage -Duser=admin -Dpass=guessing -Dip=200.0.0.1 -Dport=4444 -Dhash=${GIT_HASH} -Dbuildnumber=${BUILD_NUM}"
    }
}
```

**Problem 2**

`env.BUILD_NUMBER` is a Groovy statement, instead `mvn` gets executed inside a shell instance by the `sh` command.

For that reason I suggest you to use the `BUILD_NUM` variable way.

Comment: Thanks for your response! There were two parts to this problem, first, global variables were defined at the top of the file as `def GIT_HASh = null` as you suggested. Second, in the maven command, removing the brackets around the variable let it pass through to Jenkins. I.e using `-Dbuildnumber=$BUILD_NUM` instead of `-Dbuildnumber=${BUILD_NUM}`